# Same chars will be printed multiple times in React, but why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to print out a raising text segment in React, but every char gets printed twice.

So hopefully someone has an idea.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import Test from './test.js';

function Root(){
    return(
        <React.StrictMode>
            <Test/>
        </React.StrictMode>
    )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<Root/>);
```

**test.js**

```
import {useCallback,useEffect,useState} from 'react';

export default function Test(){

    const [outText,setOutText] = useState('');

    const drawText = useCallback(text=>{
        let index=0;
        let textInterval;
        const callback = ()=>{
            if (index>=text.length-1){
                clearInterval(textInterval);
                return;
            }
            setOutText(t=>{
                if (text[index]==='\n'){
                    return t+'<br>';
                } else {
                    return t+text[index];
                }
            });
            index++;
        };
        textInterval=setInterval(callback,20);
    });

    useEffect(()=>{
        const text = `
            a text is written here
            and should be printed step by step
        `.split('');
        drawText(text);
    },[])

    return (
        <div id="test">
            <div className="out-text" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:outText}} />
        </div>
    );

}
```

Every character should be appended to `outText` only once and not twice. Please avoid solutions that rely on `index % 2` as they will not resolve my issue.

edit:
After Stackoverflow closed this Question before i can give you my solution, here the solution which was working for my case.

**test.js**

```
import {useCallback,useEffect,useState} from 'react';

export default function Test(){

    const [outText,setOutText] = useState('');
    const [index,setIndex] = useState(-1);

    const text = `
        any text is written here
        and should be printed step by step
    `.split('')

    const mapChar = useCallback(c=>{
        if (c==='\n'){
            return '<br/>';
        } else{
            return c;
        }
    });

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(index<0||
            index>=text.length){
            return;
        }
        let timeout;
        if (index===0){
            timeout=setTimeout(()=>{
                setIndex(i=>i+1);
                setOutText(t=>t+mapChar(text[index]));
            },500);
        } else {
            timeout=setTimeout(()=>{
                setIndex(i=>i+1);
                setOutText(t=>t+mapChar(text[index]));
            },20);
        }
        return ()=>{
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        };
    },[index]);

    // just an entry point,
    // normally a scroll.y value from a parent container
    // is inside the dependencies
    useEffect(()=>{
        //if (scroll.y>targetScrollPosition&&
        //    index<0){
            setIndex(0);
        // }
    },[/* scroll.y */])

    return (
        <div id="test">
            <div className="out-text" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:outText}} />
        </div>
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to debug your code and find the problem, but I'd like to offer an alternative solution. The following uses a hook to manage the value of the string.

```
function useTextWriter(text: string, delay: number) {
  const [outText, setOutText] = useState("");
  const chars = useRef(text.split(""));

  useEffect(() => {
    const i = setInterval(() => {
      if (chars.current.length) {
        const char = chars.current.shift();
        setOutText(`${outText}${char}`);
      }
    }, delay);

    return () => clearInterval(i);
  });

  return outText;
}
```

Example usage would be:

```
export default function Test() {
  const value = useTextWriter(`a text`, 1000);

  return (
    <div id="test">
      <div className="out-text">
        {value}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @pilchard Thanks for spotting, fixed

Comment: your textWriter-function is working, but it's importtant for me, that the writer can be called inside a useEffect-function, so your function won't be a solution for me, sry, but ty for your answer

Answer (score 0):

A more React idiomatic solution:

```js
const text = ["a text is written here", "and should be printed step by step"];

function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(-1);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (index >= text.join("").length) {
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(() => setIndex((prev) => prev + 1), 100);
  }, [index]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="text">
        {text[0].split("").map((x, i) => (
          <span className={i < index ? "visible" : ""} key={`${x}-${i}`}>
            {x}
          </span>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="text">
        {text[1].split("").map((x, i) => (
          <span
            className={i + text[0].length < index ? "visible" : ""}
            key={`${x}-${i}`}
          >
            {x}
          </span>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App/>);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.text span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.text span.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
   <div id="root"></div>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: your solution was very helpful, i did not used your full solution, since i noticed that a simple task like that is quiet complex to programm without getting render errors, i will spend more time in webpack itself and less in react, the solution for my requirements will follow